# HTML alignment challenge

Tags: html, css

If I have a stack of textboxes and a button, e.g.

```
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<button>Right align me</button>
```

How can I right align the right edges of the textboxes and the button without specifying the size of everything?

Update - perhaps my question wasn't clear. Some of the answers propose right aligning everything. Which would look like this:

[image: right aligned]

But I actually want the textboxes to be left aligned, but the button to right align to the edge of those text boxes. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you want it to look like? Something more like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/N1jHR.png?

Answer (score 3):

If you wrap them all in a block element (such as a `<div>`), you can specify `text-align: right;` on that `<div>`, and it will align everything to the right, regardless of size.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/TG2Kq/):

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="text" /><br/>
    <input type="text" /><br/>
    <input type="text" /><br/>
    <button>Right align me</button>
</div>
```

```
#container{
    text-align: right;
}
```

---

### Update:

Based on the changes to your question, would [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/jQMsp/1/) work better?
It aligns the button to the very right of the longest input, and to the bottom. The only disadvantage is that if you have content below the box, you'll need to add some extra margin, so it doesn't overlap with the button.

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="text" /><br/>
    <input type="text" /><br/>
    <input type="text" /><br/>
    <button>Right align me</button>
</div>
```

```
#container{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    
    /* Add 25px margin to prevent overlap with the button */
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

button{
    position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 100%;
    
    /* Make it look more normal-sized */
    width: 120px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Updated the question - I don't want everything right aligned.

Comment: @ConfusedNoob I simply did what you had originally asked. I don't know what you want it to do now, hence my comment on the question.

Comment: @ConfusedNoob I updated my answer to reflect what I think you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Set the widths of your `input` and `button` elements to 100%, and use a container to set their actual widths:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <button>Right align me</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container { width: 200px; }
input { width: 100%; }
button { width: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a div and use text-align:right and either float:left or display:inline-block on it. The first one works in ie6.

Like this:

```
<div style=" text-align: right; float:left;">
     <input type="text" /><br/>
     <input type="text" /><br/>
     <input type="text" /><br/>
     <button>Right align me</button>
</div>
```

or

```
<div style=" text-align: right; display: inline:block">
     <input type="text" /><br/>
     <input type="text" /><br/>
     <input type="text" /><br/>
     <button>Right align me</button>
</div>
```

You can also use a good, old table, it's not recommended though.

```
<table style="text-align:right">
    <tr><td>
         <input type="text" /><br/>
         <input type="text" /><br/>
         <input type="text" /><br/>
         <button>Right align me</button>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just float the inputs and buttons, while clearing the floats in the br tag.

```
<style>
    input { float: right; }
    br { clear:both;}
    button { float:right;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `float:right` the elements inside the specified element, so they will be right aligned, like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/4YNrD/).

Comment: In the example you set the width to 400px. Exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Then just don't set any width... you asked to right align the right edges of the textboxes, my example just does that. Next time please be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="float: left;">
    <input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="text" /><br />
    <button style="float: right;">Right align me</button>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Wrap the elements in a div. Floating the div left will left-align it and make its size conform to the size of its contents. Floating the button right will flush the button to the right. The clear div is there in case you want elements you add after this div to be below it, not to its right side.

Answer (score -2):

to accomplish what you are looking for try the following:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" /><br/>
</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><button>Right align me</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If you do not like tables, I think that you must use JavaScript to get the TextBox size (maybe it change from a browser to another) then set some CSS to the Button.

Comment: Tables for layout is a terrible HTML practice, and it really shouldn't be used except when looking for extreme legacy support.